# What is a CSP error in AngularJS 1?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a chrome plugin with AngularJS 1.5 dependencies. 
In that, I am getting this error.

```
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

I am not able to understand the problem behind this.

The same app is working fine for me on a web app. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Have a look on this article.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 1.5 uses some features that can conflict with certain restrictions that are applied when using CSP (Content Security Policy) rules.

At the header level, mention this.

Also, have a look at
[Angular ngCSP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)
.

Comment: Are you sure this will help?

Answer (score 1):

The ng-csp directive is used to change the security policy of AngularJS.

With the ng-csp directive set, AngularJS will not run any eval functions, and it will not inject any inline styles.

Setting the value of the ng-csp directive to no-unsafe-eval, will stop AngularJS from running any eval functions, but allow injecting inline styles.

Setting the value of the ng-csp directive to no-inline-style, will stop AngularJS from injecting any inline styles, but allow eval functions.

Using the ng-csp directive is necessary when developing apps for Google Chrome Extensions or Windows Apps.

**Example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-csp>
...
...
</html>
```